# В админке битрикса (bitrix) на страницах подгружаются не все скрипты и стили по причине 403?

Tags: javascript, css, битрикс

Установлен на openserver. Что может быть?

PS Гуглил, в .access.php правил в .htaccess тоже ... рядом в той же папке лежат стили и нормально загружаются, со скриптами так же. В  конфиге сервера все как надо

Comment: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ArtemP А права на файлах проверяли?

Comment: в винде во вкладке дополнительно снял галочку "только для чтения"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724718/error-403-in-loading-resources-like-css-and-js-in-my-index-php